# Ambiguous wording in the help section for mentioning tags in the editor

Tags: discussion, help-center, editor, user-experience

I personally found the first paragraph confusing until I read the second one.
I think it should read `To talk about a tag on Stack Overflow, ...` instead.

[image]
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tags

---

**EDIT** This what the same Help Center section looks like on the non-meta site:

[image]

https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tags

Comment: Maybe *"To talk about a Stack Overflow tag on Meta Stack Overflow, use..."*

Comment: Did you notice that you were reading the *Meta* Help Center? That's why it talks about "Meta Stack Overflow". That text is automatically filled in with the name of the site whose Help Center you're looking at.

Comment: @CodyGray yep, but still a UX flaw.

Comment: @CodyGray Yes I did, thank you for checking. I just edited the question to include a screenshot of the Help Center on the non-meta site; comparing the two *may* be useful in understanding what happened and how to address the issue, if issue it is.

Comment: @CodyGray: Indeed, the same bug appears on all per-site metas. [On math.SE meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tags), for example, it says "a tag on Mathematics Meta Stack Exchange" while talking about how to link to a tag on the main site. I suspect the code is just interpolating the wrong site name in that paragraph. What's adding to the confusion is that, with some mental gymnastics, it's also possible to parse the current phrasing in a way that makes it technically correct (as it's talking about how to link to _a tag on the main site_ from _a post on the meta site_).

Comment: What does it say about me, @Ilmari, that the "mental gymnastics" of which you speak are my natural instincts?

Comment: @CodyGray: Probably just that you first looked at the text expecting it to make sense as written, and indeed your brain found a way to make sense of it. It's like one of those trick pictures where you can see either a vase or two faces, and it takes some effort to get your brain to switch from one to the other. (All that said, I'd say the broader context suggests that there's indeed a mistake: the two examples in that section, as currently written, are contrasting "tag[s] on Meta Stack Overflow" with "tags on this meta site", which makes no sense.)